# What are `.` and `*` means in a c macro?

Tags: c, linux, macros, kernel, ld

From [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h#L583) what are `.` and `*` means in a c macro?

```
583 #define INITCALLS                                                       \
584         *(.initcallearly.init)                                          \
585         VMLINUX_SYMBOL(__early_initcall_end) = .;                       \
586         *(.initcall0.init)                                              \
587         *(.initcall0s.init)                                             \
588         *(.initcall1.init)                                              \
589         *(.initcall1s.init)                                             \
590         *(.initcall2.init)                                              \
591         *(.initcall2s.init)                                             \
592         *(.initcall3.init)                                              \
593         *(.initcall3s.init)                                             \
594         *(.initcall4.init)                                              \
595         *(.initcall4s.init)                                             \
596         *(.initcall5.init)                                              \
597         *(.initcall5s.init)                                             \
598         *(.initcallrootfs.init)                                         \
599         *(.initcall6.init)                                              \
600         *(.initcall6s.init)                                             \
601         *(.initcall7.init)                                              \
602         *(.initcall7s.init)
603
```

Comment: That's not C, it's a linker script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a linker script. The section merging and placement is done by the linker. A programmer can control how the sections are merged and at what locations they are placed in memory through a linker script file. The file you referred to was doing just that.

The .(dot) refers to the link section and the wild card character * is used instead of individually specifying multiple file names containing the same named link section.

Refer: http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.10/ld_3.html